# Is the sentence "you will find me in fine state" grammatical?

Tags: quotations

There's a dinner scene in *Red Dragon* (2002) where Hannibal quotes Horace's letter to
Tibullus:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHUgvhExOfo

> As for me, when you want a laugh, you will find me in fine state, fat and sleek, a true hog of Epicurus's herd.

It sounded rather awkward to me without the indefinite article 'a' preceding 'fine state'.

(Edit* Grammarly also suggests adding 'a' for the above quote citing 'article usage', but if I use 'condition' instead Grammarly reports nothing wrong')

This seems to be the translation used but I couldn't find the translator: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Horace

Here's a different translation from *[The Letters of Horace Presented to Modern Readers](https://books.google.com/books?id=3bEsAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA18&lpg=PA18&dq=horace%20letter%20to%20tibullus&source=bl&ots=i0j6JYlob5&sig=YKMCuGnkS8JHTnpiYKpLbVBxSao&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjfuYmd4tPcAhVm1oMKHTl0BHYQ6AEwB3oECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=horace%20letter%20to%20tibullus&f=false)*

> If you want to be amused, come and see me now, for I am fat and sleek and in fine condition, a very pig of the herd of Epicurus.

Here the translation sounds perfectly natural to me though I couldn't pinpoint if it's the use of 'condition' rather than 'state' or the lack of 'find me in...' that made the difference.

Another translation I found on Loeb Classical Library has this:

> As for me, when you want a laugh, you will find me in fine fettle, fat and sleek, a hog from Epicurus's herd.

This also sounds a bit more natural to me than 'fine state'. In fact, introducing an article ('a fine condition', 'a fine fettle') here only makes it sound wrong. so I'm confused why I felt compelled to add one before 'fine state' in the first place.

Is there a reason why the second sentence *feels* wrong? Or can you substitute any synonym for 'condition' here?

*The bike is in good condition* (sounds correct to me)

*The bike is in good state* (sounds wrong to me)

Another example using 'find':

*He found the child in a pitiful state* (sounds correct to me)

*He found the child in a pitiful condition* (unsure)

Comment: This is not a grammar issue—the sentence is fine as it stands, and your "correction" uses *the exact same grammar* with one noun replaced—but merely one of style. Your vocabulary choice simply differs from that of the screenwriter.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was grammar related and I didn't know if I was alone in finding it awkward. I typed it out in a chatbox beforehand and  Grammarly also underlined 'fine state' and suggested adding 'a' so I thought there was something here. If I used 'condition' instead Grammarly reported nothing wrong.

Comment: Grammarly is a dunce. Pay it no mind.

Comment: Note: It is customary to use the indefinite article with *state*. That doesn't mean it must *always* be used that way.

Comment: I googled "in fine state" and "in a fine state" and found that both the terms are used in websites and even scholarly published articles. My hypothesis is that one notable person - perhaps the translator of the letters of Horace - might have forgot to add an article before 'fine state'. And other thought it must be right. So, omitting an article before 'fine state' became common.

Comment: @Syed Danish Anwar - your hypothesis is incorrect. 'In fine state' is a rather old fashioned and formal construction. It is not incorrect or a mistake, and its widespread appearance is not the result of a copied error.